# space between camelCase string, why does my code not work?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

in JavaScript:

```
function solution(string) {
    
  let stringCharArr = string.split("");
  
  if(stringCharArr.every(char => char === char.toLowerCase())){
    return string;
  } 
  
  for(let stringChar of stringCharArr){
    let indexOfChar = stringCharArr.indexOf(stringChar)
    if(stringChar === stringChar.toUpperCase() && stringChar !== ' '){
      stringCharArr.splice(indexOfChar, 0, ' ')
    }
  }
  
  let replaceRegex = /,/g
  let newString = stringCharArr.join().replace(replaceRegex, '');
  
  return newString;
}
```

The goal of my function is to replace a camelCased-string with a space before the camelCased letter. I can't figure out why my function doesn't work. It's a challenge on codewars.

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work? What's the input, the current output and the expected output? FWIW, you can replace `let newString = stringCharArr.join().replace(replaceRegex, '');` with just `let newString = stringCharArr.join('')`.

Comment: Your `indexOfChar` looks suspect, surely that will struggle with any duplicate characters?

Comment: Why not `/([a-z])([A-Z])/\1 \2/g`?

Comment: @DBS ah, that could be a problem. i'll try it with a normal for loop instead and stringCharArr[i] i think.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for something like this?

```js
function solution(string) {
  let newString = '';
  for (let char of  string) {
    if (char === char.toUpperCase() && char !== ' ')
      newString += " " + char;
    else newString += char
  }
  return newString.toLowerCase().replace(/^\ */g, '');
}


console.log(solution("ThisIsATest"));
console.log(solution("ThisIsATEST"));
console.log(solution("this is all lowercase"));
```

Or use regex:

```js
const fromCamelCaseToSeparated = (str) => str.replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1') .replace(/^./, function(str){ return str.toUpperCase(); })


console.log(fromCamelCaseToSeparated("ThisIsATest"));
console.log(fromCamelCaseToSeparated("this is a test"));
console.log(fromCamelCaseToSeparated("AnotherTEST"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It all looks overly complicated. Here is a oneliner:

```js
const addSpaces = inputString => inputString.split("")
  .map(c => /[A-Z]/.test(c) ? ` ${c}` : c).join("");
console.log(addSpaces("ThisCamelcasedStringShouldContainSpacesBeforeUppercaseCharacters"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If your only goal is to return a new string containing spaces between each word, this is an extremely simple way to do it.

```js
function solution(str) {
    let newStr = ''
    for (const i in str) {
        if (str[i].match('[A-Z]')) {
            newStr += ' ' + str[i].toLowerCase()
        } else {
            newStr += str[i]
        }
    }
    return newStr
}

console.log(solution('helloAndWelcome'))
// hello and welcome
```

Answer (score -2):

You iterate over `stringCharArr` and update `stringCharArr` in that loop. You can use `replace()` instead

```
"camelCaseString".replace(/[A-Z]/g, " $&")
```

```js
console.log("camelCaseString".replace(/[A-Z]/g, " $&"))
```